# Pass CurrentValueSubject value wrapped in an AnyPublisher to another class

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, combine

Showing you my code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> { get }
    
    func saveLocalNotifications(_ enabled: Bool) throws
}

final class UserSettingsClass {
    private var repository: CoreDataRepo
    
    private var isLocalNotificationsEnabledSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Error>(false) 
// I make it private so that no other classes can change it from outside,
// I can only subscribe on its values.
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(repository: CoreDataRepo) {
        self.repository = repository
        binding()
    }
}

extension UserSettingsClass: SomeProtocol {
    var isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
        return isLocalNotificationsEnabledSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func saveLocalNotifications(_ enabled: Bool) throws {
        var userSettings = userSettings // this is core data object... 
        
        userSettings?.isLocalNotificationsEnabled = enabled 
// this is the important part, it has this toggle.
// I need to be able to send this value to my LocalNotificaitonsService class and based
// on this value understand whether I can send local notifications or not.
        
        if isLocalNotificationsEnabledSubject.value != enabled {
            throw someError
        }
        
        isLocalNotificationsEnabledSubject.send(userSettings?.isLocalNotificationsEnabled ?? false)
    }
}
```

Here is how I bind it to my publisher so that I could subscribe to the value that I send in the saveLocalNotifications method:

```
private func binding() {
        isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                    do {
                        try saveLocalNotifications(value) // recursion here + not handling error properly...
                    } catch {
                        return
                    }
                }
                
            ).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

This code causes recursion that leads to my app crashing.
Here is how I try to use it in my local notifications manager:

```
private let isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>
    
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
public init(isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>) {
        self.isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher = isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher
    }
extension LocalNotificationsManager: SomeOtherProtocol {
    public func requestNotificationAuthorization() throws {
        isLocalNotificationsEnabledPublisher
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                    if value == true {
                        Task {
                            try await self?.center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

So basically this code does not work properly because I do not understand how to get the subject value in the local notifications manager class. I need to be able to sink on the toggle value from the user settings and decide if I can or can not send local notifications.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that the general architecture of this could probably be refactored, but I'm guessing you could solve the immediate recursion problem by adding `removeDuplicates()` in the places where you subscribe to the publisher.

Comment: @jnpdx, the architecture is indeed painful to work with. Could you please explain why should removeDuplicates() work? How would this work in a classic mvvm or mv for swift ui work?

Comment: You have recursion because you call `saveLocalNotifications` and then that triggers the combine chain again. `removeDuplicates` will prevent the chain from running if it had the same value as before. Doesn't have anything to do with `mvvm` or `mv`

Comment: I thought you were talking about the architecture of the app :D
thanks, just tested it and it works perfectly. Can you write an answer for this so that I accept it and upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have recursion because you call `saveLocalNotifications` and then that triggers the Combine chain again, since that in turn calls `isLocalNotificationsEnabledSubject.send(...)`.

To prevent the recursion, you could use `removeDuplicates` in the Combine chain where you subscribe to `isLocalNotificationsEnabledSubject`

That being said, you may wan to reconsider your architecture so that the recursion isn't possible.

Comment: thanks, any ideas why it would send true instead of false event if I explicitly make it false in the line there the `.send()` happens?

Comment: It would not. I’d need to see a [mre] to debug whatever is going on.